# I'm learning java,currently a beginner.I was trying to use method parameters but this unexpected error has popped up

Tags: java, methods, parameters

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //A method is a block of code which only runs when it is called
        sayHello(name:"Raj",age:20);

    }
    //method should be defined in the class

    public static void sayHello(String name, int age){
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

This code is returning folowwing errors for line 7:
')' expected
';' expected
'not a statement'

I had expected the code to run as is should but I can't seem to identify the error.

Comment: what about doing: "sayHello("Raj", 20);"

Comment: did you type `name:` and `age:`  ? These should NOT be included in code, correct is `sayHello("Raj", 20);` The parameter names (`name` and `age`) are displayed by some IDEs to *help* identify the arguments, but they are not part of code (should be displayed in a different color/background) - probably you watched some video tutorial and they did not explain that *detail*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in java there is no named- but positional-parameters only

so this is invalid:

```
sayHello(name:"Raj",age:20);
```

do instead:

```
sayHello("Raj", 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and ran it. If you pasted the full code, there is something wrong with your method input parameters. It should be sayHello("Raj",20), not sayHello(name:"Raj",age:20), just pass in the actual parameters in the order of the method definition line parameters, and then I noticed in your method The attributes name and age do not play a role in the method at all. When defining a function, you should ensure that each formal parameter plays a role. If you want to enter name and age to print to the console, you can refer to the following code

public class MyClass
{
public static void main(String[] args){

```
    //A method is a block of code which only runs when it is called
    sayHello("Raj",20);

}
//method should be defined in the class

public static void sayHello(String name, int age){
        //  output the name and its age
    System.out.println("Hello!,name:"+name+",age:"+age);
}
}
```